# Confused on how to represent these items in a class diagram

Tags: java, android, uml, class-diagram

I am unsure how to represent the following 3 in a class diagram or whether some of they should be represented at all in a class diagram. I have gone through the UML spec but am still confused on the ones below:

1) 2) 3) are all in a another class named `Vehicle`, how would you represent each of them in a class diagram.

1) `List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>(20);`
2) `Cars car1;`
3) `import com.esoxjem.carmanual.Cars;`

4) What if a cars object is created in the `Car` class itself. How would that be represented?

If someone could draw example of the above situation it would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: So your cars have found a way to reproduce themselves (4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only see one class... CARS. The diagram would be only one class

Comment: I suppose it would be something like this [link](http://imgur.com/a/QmnZs)

Comment: Hi @Julian, what about the import? How would that be represented on the diagram if at all?

Comment: The class diagram is a high level representation. Only classes and their relationship matters

Answer (score 0):

I am making some assumptions here as it seems some details have been omitted in the question (there is a mentioning of a spec, what is included in this spec? Are there more objects?). It would be useful to post further information that may help in providing a correct answer.

Based on the information present, the list of three items can be interpreted as follows:

1. `List<Cars>` - this could represent something like a car dealership (as an example), maybe the list contains the cars sold at this dealership?
2. `Cars` - a car object
3. `import com.esoxjem.carmanual.Cars` - this seems like it is refering to the Cars object in Item 2 above.

So the way I see it there are two objects (CarDealership & Car). The cardinality between CarDealership and Car would be one-to-many (1-*).

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to do a comment but maybe there is a mix between Car, a class modeling a car, and cars which is a list of Car, but Cars is not a class. Is that right ?

if this case, the first one is an association between Vehicule and Car with a cardinality *, the second is an association between Vehicule and Car with a cardinality 1.

As already said, "import com.esoxjem.carmanual.Cars - this seems like it is refering to the Cars object in Item 2 above."

Then it is needed to choose if association are "simple" association or a composite. Please see section 9.5.3 of UML 2.5  (march 2015)